# Login page error in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-page

I have a login page in which i have written code to login the admin part but it is not working i don't know what the problem is this the code is correct still getting unauthorized access. help me out

```
  string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ottscon"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select UserName,Password from login where UserName=@userid and Password=@passid", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", TextBox1.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passid", TextBox2.ToString());
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds= new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
            {

               Session["login"] = TextBox1.Text;
               Response.Redirect("admintrator123/Default.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Unauthorized Access";
                Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you storing passwords as plain text?

Comment: That's kinda dangerous, you should really think about storing them in hashed form. When you execute query directly on the DB are getting any result for parameters you are passing?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to check what is there in the dataset `ds`? Run your SQL profiler and check what query is going in.

Comment: try change .tostring() to .text

Comment: First check whether u r getting row in the dataset or not. If not check if the parameters are correctly assigning to the sql command or not.

Comment: yes i debug my project and while debugging i found no value comes in dataset that's why it is not authenticating but don't how to get up from this error

Comment: You should set a breakpoint and look at the SQL command parameter values, if it looks ok try the SQLstatement in SQL Mgmt Studio.

Comment: solved i change the dataset from datatable

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing values properly

`TextBox1.ToString()` is wrong

use

`TextBox1.Text`

Comment: still not able to access the admin dashboard

Answer (score 0):

First use the value of the text inside the textbox (the existing `ToString()` is returning the type of the object `TextBox`):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passid", TextBox2.Text);
```

Try using this SQL to check if the record exist (inside the `new SqlCommand()`):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM [login]
    WHERE UserName=@userid and Password=@passid
)
THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
```

So you can then check on a bool and not on a row existance and have more understanding on what's happening.

After this you can read the value this way:

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        bool exist = reader.GetBoolean(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try

```
logincommand = "Select UserName,Password from login where UserName='"+TextBox1.Text+"' and Password='"+TextBox2.Text+"'"
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(logincommand ,con);
```

and delete

```
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", TextBox1.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passid", TextBox2.ToString());
```

Comment: SQL Injection attack!!

Comment: This exposes query to the SQL injection attack!